# Layout/Drawing in Workflows or a node for a Sub-Workflow

Tags: orange

I am creating Orange Workflows for a few days, therefore I am pretty new.
I want to spread my workflows with colleagues such that they can also use them and further develop them.
I am facing now the issue, that I am having workflows with several data sources and therefore I have to preprocess the data in several nodes (Selections on Rows/Columns, Python code, Unique, Feature Constructor, Merge, ...). This leads to pretty complex workflows (until it gets to the point of the interesting nodes for visualization, analysis, ...) and it will be difficult for others to read them. Now my questions:

- Does anyone also has such problems and how did you solve this.
- Some basic drawing functions would already help to mark areas in my workflow. But I think something like this is not available.
- Is there a node for a sub-workflow such that I can do the whole preprocessing in a sub-workflow that is triggered automatically within the main workflow.

Any hints are appreciated.